# I don't know about return type in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

TYPESCRIPT 3.4.3

I want to make function like this

`exportObjectUnit({ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 }, ['b', 'c'])`

OUTPUT
`{ a: 1, d: 4 };`

I don't know how to typing this function's return type

```js
export const exportObjectKey = <T, K extends keyof T>(value: T, exports: K[]) => {
  const returnValue = {};

  Object.keys(value)
    .filter(key => {
      if (exports.indexOf(key) !== -1) {
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    })
    .map(key => {
      returnValue[key] = value[key];
    });

  return returnValue as T;
};
```

If I use this function, return value still have types (With the exception of second string array parameter)

----------EDIT----------------

```js
export const exportObjectKey = <T>(value: T, exports: Array<keyof T>) => {
  const returnValue = {};

  Object.keys(value)
    .filter(key => {
      if (exports.indexOf(key as keyof T) !== -1) {
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    })
    .map(key => {
      returnValue[key] = value[key];
    });

  return returnValue as T;
};
```

I don't know how to return. 
Removing seconds parameter array property from first object

-----------EDIT 2----------------

```js
type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;

export const exportObjectKey = <T, K extends keyof T>(value: T, omit: K): Omit<T, K> => {
  delete value[omit];
  return value;
};
export const exportObjectKeys = <T, K extends Array<keyof T>>(value: T, removes: K) =>
  removes.reduce((object, key) => exportObjectKey(object, key), value);

// This is not perfect version

const a = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
const keyOmitOne = exportObjectKey(a, 'b');
// When I type keyOmitOne.
// Type definition available, It works (a, c)

// ------------------------------------------

// But, when I use exportObjectKeys
const b = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
const keyOmitArray = exportObjectKey(b, ['b', 'c']);
// I thought type definition works (a available)
// But there is no definition in b value)
```

Comment: Why are you using generics? It seems you know exactly what the input and output is. Generics are meant for functions that have to work with different kinds of input, and then output that same type. In your case, can't you just write an `interface` or `type` for the input and output types?

Comment: The input object and output object is different every call (parameter changing)

Comment: Isn't `value` (and `returnValue`) always of the type `object`? You use `Object.keys()` on `value` and initialise `returnValue` as `{}`

Comment: I did not understand your comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shouldn't be hard I guess?

```
type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>

function exportObjectUnit<T extends Object, K extends (keyof T)[]>(obj: T, ...keys: K): Omit<T, K[number]> {
    keys.forEach(k => delete obj[k])
    return obj
}

const t1 = exportObjectUnit({ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4})
const t2 = exportObjectUnit({ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4} , 'a')
const t3 = exportObjectUnit({ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4} , 'a', 'b')
const t4 = exportObjectUnit({ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4} , 'a', 'b', 'c')
const t5 = exportObjectUnit({ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4} , 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
```

Comment: Thank you, This is the best answer

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you want, but without generics, you could use `index signature` to input and output an object with unknown keys.

```
type MyObject = { [key: string]: number }

function doSomething(obj: MyObject, arr: string[]) : MyObject {
    let a : MyObject = {a:3, b:4}
    return a
}

doSomething({a:4, b:4, c:4, d:2}, ["a", "d"])
```